# Does android mobile has any error log file to debug cause for auto switch off?

Tags: android, shutdown, logfiles, system-shutdown

Sometimes we see the device restarts automatically, while few other times I had found it switching off after long time, even battery was not low.
So if we want to trace back of what actually has caused this, does we have any log file in device memory which has the cause of shutdown or restart ?

Like we get the dump for the other O.S. for any errors occured causing it to restart/shutdown in specific error log file. Similarly does android has such ?

It may be anywhere , even in internal memory, so with root privileges I can go into looking for it.
Any thoughts ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Terminal on your phone just tupe in
`su

 logcat`

If not enable DebbugingMode on your phone, connect it with your PC/Mac, open Eclipse and go to Debug.
There it will show the log of the phone.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I know the logcat view, I am working on android development. What I mean was can I have a log of events that has caused auto-switched off of phone few hours back outside somewhere not connected to PC,  so later when the phone is switched on and connected to PC, can I see what was the cause? Logcat gives event log of running status from time connected to PC.

Comment: You should what if this happens more than once so keep it connected to the PC, save the logcat to a file and you might be able to see what happened right before the turn off... I don't know a way to do that without the pc connection...

Comment: Yes if have it connected to PC we have logcat, but unfortunately this is very random.

Comment: Than make let it connected until the device turns itself off. You have no other possibility than that to get the logcat of the moment it went off...